# Issue deploying a FormPage using Classify

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, cloud-deploy

I developed this code that allows me to recognize what breed is the dog in the inserted image (for the time being developed only for five breeds of dogs), however, when I go to insert the image in output gives me a series of vectors . could you tell me where I'm wrong?
I am attaching the code.

```
dobermann = {-> "Dobermann", -> "Dobermann", -> "Dobermann", -> 
    "Dobermann", -> "Dobermann"};
rottweiler = {-> "Rottweiler", -> "Rottweiler", -> "Rottweiler", -> 
    "Rottweiler", -> "Rottweiler"};
alano = {-> "Alano", -> "Alano", -> "Alano", -> "Alano", -> "Alano"};
labrador = {-> "Labrador", -> "Labrador", -> "Labrador", -> 
    "Labrador", -> "Labrador" };
husky = {-> "Husky", -> "Husky", -> "Husky", -> "Husky", -> "Husky" };
dogTypeSet = {dobermann, rottweiler, alano, labrador, husky};
dogTypes = Flatten[dogTypeSet];
class = Classify[
   Flatten[{dobermann, rottweiler, alano, labrador, husky}]];
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage["image" -> "Image", 
  Column[{image, "This is a " <> ToString[net[image]] <> "dog"}], 
  AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "What dog is that?", 
    "Description" -> 
     "Enter an image of a dog and I'll tell you what it is"|>], 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Before the arrows are inserted the images of each dog breed. I had to remove them otherwise the code became incomprehensible.

Comment: There appears to be an issue in your code - you are calling `net` rather than `class` in your `FormPage`. In `Column[{image, "This is a " <> ToString[net[image]] <> "dog"}]`, replace `net` with `class`.

Comment: Done, but it gives me the following error: ClassifierFunction::mlincfttp: Incompatible variable type (Image) and variable value (image).

Comment: Please see my answer - there was another error in your code I didn't immediately spot.

Answer (score 3):

There are some errors in your code.

A working `CloudDeploy` statement is below.

```
CloudDeploy[
 FormPage["image" -> "Image", 
  Column[{#image, 
     "This is a " <> ToString[class[#image]] <> "dog"}] &, 
  AppearanceRules -> <|"Title" -> "What dog is that?", 
    "Description" -> 
     "Enter an image of a dog and I'll tell you what it is"|>], 
 Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Firstly, `FormPage` takes a function as the second argument, rather than an expression. Thus, you must use `#image` rather than `image` and close the expression with a `$`. Secondly, you misnamed `class` as `net`.

I have tried this myself with a day/night classifier (rather than dog breed classifier) and it works well.

[image: daynight]

Comment: Thank you very much. One last thing, how could I train a neural network so that I can recognize any breed of dog. Doing as I did I use too much time.

Comment: That is a separate question and you should open a new one accordingly. If you found this answer useful for your specific question, you should mark it as accepted.
A starting point for a dog breed classifier would be the [Stanford Dogs dataset](http://vision.stanford.edu/aditya86/ImageNetDogs/) which has many images of 120 different breeds. You would need to import the data to Mathematica and you could run Classify in it in a similar way.

Comment: Now I try, in case I open a new discussion.
Thank you.

Comment: If instead I wanted to propose an interface on mathematica and not on the cloud, what should I change?

Comment: @Pasquale Please consider opening a new question for follow-up questions, and consider marking this answer as accepted. Comments aren't good for long discussions!

Comment: I should use a code like this: `Row[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[file]], Dynamic[file]}], Button["Load file", im = Import[file]] Dynamic[im]`                            but I do not know where to put it