# Creating a GUI for a classifier

Tags: gui-construction, machine-learning

I developed the following code which is suitable for cloud deployment.  However, in order to avoid the problems of the cloud, I would like to create an user interface that runs in a Mathematica notebook. How could I do that?

My code is as follows:

```
dobermann = 
  {-> "Dobermann", -> "Dobermann", -> "Dobermann", -> "Dobermann", -> "Dobermann"};
rottweiler = 
  {-> "Rottweiler", -> "Rottweiler", -> "Rottweiler", -> "Rottweiler", -> "Rottweiler"};
alano = 
  {-> "Alano", -> "Alano", -> "Alano", -> "Alano", -> "Alano"};
labrador = 
  {-> "Labrador", -> "Labrador", -> "Labrador", -> "Labrador", -> "Labrador" };
husky = 
  {-> "Husky", -> "Husky", -> "Husky", -> "Husky", -> "Husky" };

dogTypeSet = {dobermann, rottweiler, alano, labrador, husky};
class = Classify[Flatten[{dobermann, rottweiler, alano, labrador, husky}]];

CloudDeploy[
  FormPage[
    "image" -> "Image", 
    Column[{#image, "This is a " <> ToString[class[#image]]}] &, 
    AppearanceRules -> 
      <|"Title" -> "What dog is that?", 
        "Description" -> "Enter an image of a dog and I'll tell you what it is", 
        "SubmitLabel" -> "Classify"|>, PageTheme -> "Blue"], 
  Permissions -> "Public"]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue deploying a FormPage using Classify](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/189146/issue-deploying-a-formpage-using-classify)

Comment: I asked this question in a comment on that post and I was told to create another one

Comment: @NikiEstner They're not duplicates; one is asking to fix the code for cloud deployment, the other is asking how to create such an interface using Mathematica frontend programming.

Comment: What is this: `{-> "Dobermann"...`?

Comment: before the arrow you have to insert the photo of the dog (for example of a Dobermann)

Comment: @Kuba I should use a code like this:`Row[{FileNameSetter[Dynamic[file]], Dynamic[file]}],
Button["Load file", im = Import[file]]
Dynamic[im]` but I do not know where to put it.

Comment: @Pasquale why do you mean where to put it? In a cell and evaluate.

Comment: @Kuba yes,Yes, I would like to create an interface to import the image from pc to mathematica, instead of creating a microsite.

Comment: I know. So what is the problem with the Row above?

Comment: @Kuba I would like to implement it to my code.